# iText Search, Highlight, image of result

Tags: itext, highlighting, highlight

I want to Do these tasks:
1-find a word in pdf
2-highlight all occurrences in that pdf,
3-save highlighted pdf as images of its pages.

How can I do this ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since PDFs are, for the most part, vector-based, why not draw the highlight behind the text as a filled-in box? I mean, rather than exporting the image and then re-importing into the PDF structure.

Comment: You're right , I want to find the word's places and highlight those places.After that I may have highlighted pdf in my hand, but in the end of the day I want to get an image from this highlighted pdf and show that image to the user(for security reasons).I like to have the result similar to google books.Real problems are items 1 and 2 which I have to find the places and highlight those places.I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy

It'll give you the baseline, ascent, and descent of every piece of text on the page.  It's up to you to build words and rectangles from that information.

Not Easy, but possible.

After that, you just need to call GhostScript or PDFBox or something that can render PDFs.  Hardly "the easy part", but it's a solved problem many times over.