# Reading PDF, DJVU formats in Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, djvu

What is the best way to work with PDF and DJVU formats in Ruby/Ruby On Rails?
What I need is to get number of pages and get picture of the specific page. There are will be more cases in future.

Now, I'm using command promt for this (djvulibre for DJVU, gs for PDF). It works fine, but if there is a more preferable tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/)** Ruby gem should do you and **[Djvu-tools](https://rubygems.org/gems/djvu-tools)** is the only one I have heard of for `djvu` files.

Also, some other interesting pdf options include [rails-latex](https://github.com/jacott/rails-latex) a nifty little framework for latex files in a rails server.  Latex includes some very interesting libraries such as [TikZ/Pgf](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/all/) that produce beautiful documents difficult to match in `html`.

Comment: pdf-reader is fairly low level - it can pull apart a PDF and extract the text, but it can't render a page

Answer (score 0):

the ruby-poppler bindings can render a PDF to JPG. See my answer in [1] for some sample code.

[1] [In Ruby Search PDF, highlight text found, export JPG of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000785/in-ruby-search-pdf-highlight-text-found-export-jpg-of-the-page/7019828#7019828)